# How to animate the view with pre-existing animation?

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I want to animate a view with the pre-existing animation of UIView.
I am using this code for animating the UIView -

```
CATransition *transition = [[CATransition alloc] init];
        transition.duration = 0.1;
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
        [viewToAnimate.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
```

I want to animate some other view, along with this animation.

Comment: You can use CAAnimationGroup to chain multiple animations, Did you try that ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to chain your animations. Here is example from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimationgroup).

```
let fadeOut = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
fadeOut.fromValue = 1
fadeOut.toValue = 0
fadeOut.duration = 1

let expandScale = CABasicAnimation()
expandScale.keyPath = "transform"
expandScale.valueFunction = CAValueFunction(name: kCAValueFunctionScale)
expandScale.fromValue = [1, 1, 1]
expandScale.toValue = [3, 3, 3]

let fadeAndScale = CAAnimationGroup()
fadeAndScale.animations = [fadeOut, expandScale]
fadeAndScale.duration = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic iOS animation that is:
 UIView .animate(withDuration: TimeInterval) {
        code
        }

In the code segment you can write to change the x positions of different views. whenever you will click on button that respective view's x corrdinate will animate to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!
    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!
    let finalFrameForVC = transitionContext.finalFrameForViewController(toViewController)
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()
    let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    toViewController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(finalFrameForVC, 0, bounds.size.height)
    containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(transitionContext), delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.5
        toViewController.view.frame = finalFrameForVC
        }, completion: {
            finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            fromViewController.view.alpha = 1.0
    })
}
```